# How to get lastIndex in Thymeleaf

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

In my application, I have to extract a file name from its path. I want to get the last index of '/' to extract the file name. But I have not seen any #strings function for lastIndex.

The file name has a prefix of a number and -. If I use  ${#strings.substringAfter(string, '-' )}, I get the file name but not the number pdefix.  Please suggest.

Comment: Please post your code!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `arraySplit` function that belongs to `#strings` and get the last array's element using the `#arrays.length` method.

Something like this:

```
${#strings.arraySplit(yourString, '/')[#arrays.length(#strings.arraySplit(yourString, '/')) - 1]}
```

I didn't test the code but it should work.

Comment: excellent stuff. It works perfectly. I am also trying to get the number before the underscore using substringBefore but without success. th:text="${#strings.substringBefore(#strings.arraySplit(file, '/')[#arrays.length(#strings.arraySplit(file, '/')) -1]), '_'}"

Comment: So, do a new `arraySplit(${#strings.arraySplit(yourString, '/')[#arrays.length(#strings.arraySplit(yourString, '/')) - 1]}
, '_')[0]` and get the first array's element.

Comment: You should mark my answer as the solution and upvote my answer and the comment would be fair ;)

Comment: I will do both definitely. Please give me a moment

Comment: th:text="${#strings.arraySplit({#strings.arraySplit(myString, '/')[#arrays.length(#strings.arraySplit(myString, '/')) - 1]}, '_')[0]}"    I am getting the number but it is coming as [23 instead of 23

Comment: Do you have the `[` character present in your file name?

Comment: post an example of filename you have

Comment: No.  Example file name  23_salesfigure.pdf

Comment: It is so weird, you can split it again as a trick:
`th:text="${#strings.arraySplit(${#strings.arraySplit({#strings.arraySplit(myString, '/')[#arrays.length(#strings.arraySplit(myString, '/')) - 1]}, '_')[0]}, '[')[1]`

Comment: did you find a solution?